# Youtube interaction with WINAPI GetForegroundWindow()?

Tags: c++, winapi, youtube

I'm getting a weird interaction with YouTube and a simple program that gets the window title of a window:
My small code is here:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

wstring getWindowTitle()
{
    // stores the program title
    wstring title;
    // handle to the window
    HWND handle = GetForegroundWindow();
    // length of the title
    int len = GetWindowTextLengthW(handle) + 1;
    // programs title
    wchar_t * programTitle = new wchar_t[len];
    // gets the window title
    GetWindowTextW(handle, programTitle, len);
    // adds program title to our w string to store it in
    title += programTitle;
    return title;
}

int main()
{
    wstring windowTitle;
    windowTitle = L"Title is: ";
    while (1)
{
    windowTitle = getWindowTitle();
    std::wcout << windowTitle << endl;
    Sleep(3000);
}
    return 0;
}
```

It works as long as a youtube video isn't playing. For example this is a command line text i have:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
Mozilla Firefox Start Page - Mozilla Firefox
YouTube - Mozilla Firefox
McDonalds Artisan Grilled Chicken Sandwich? FAIL! - YouTube - Mozilla Firefox
```

After i open the youtube video it won't keep update the window title anymore, it will just stay there frozen, is it something with youtube/flash player bugging up GetForegroundWindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the additional headers:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

and before the following line in your `main` function:

```
std::wcout << windowTitle << endl;
```

add the following:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

The main  problem (and not the only one in your code) is the way `wcout` handles some Unicode characters internally. So when your application meets a certain Unicode character in a foreground windows it stops the execution. It has nothing to do with the YouTube or your flash player. Read up on Unicode and Unicode in console applications.

Comment: You say I have other errors in my program, its a small program so mind telling me the others? And thanks btw it works now!

Comment: @Omar: A memory leak every 3 seconds, for example. The use of `operator+` to essentially turn a character array into a string is also questionable. Use one of the constructors instead. You also have a race condition: The window text can change in between your querying its length and retrieving it, leading to a truncated string.